# AWS Cognito User Pool Integration With Identity Pool

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement login/ sign up functionality to my iOS app using a User Pool and Identity Pool. The problem I am having is that all of the users in my user pool are receiving the same identity pool id when they call getIdentityId on the credentials provider. I cannot figure out how to remedy this. Any help would be much appreciated.

code in App Delegate:

```
var pool: AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool?
var credentialsProvider: AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider?
var dynamoMapper: AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper?

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: nil)

AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = serviceConfiguration

let userPoolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: "", clientSecret: "" , poolId: "")

AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.registerCognitoIdentityUserPoolWithConfiguration(serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: userPoolConfiguration, forKey: "UserPool")

pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "UserPool")

credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: "", identityProviderManager: pool)

let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

dynamoMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()   

return true
}
```

code in sign in view controller:

```
let user = pool!.getUser(self.email.text!)
user.getSession(self.email.text!, password: self.password.text!, validationData: nil, scopes: nil).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in

    if (task.error == nil) {

        credentialsProvider!.getIdentityId().continueWithBlock({ (task1: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
            if (task1.error != nil) {

                print("error on login")

            } else {

                print("succesful login")
            }
            return nil
        })


    } else {
        print("error")
    }
    return nil
})
```

Comment: Developer from Cognito here. This should not happen. If you are still facing this problem, we will need more details to debug this. You can reach us on aws forums and provide details eg: Identity pool id, user pool id in a  private message and we will help to debug the issue.